# Editing the source of a minimised javascript

Tags: javascript, web, minify

I'm new to Javascript and web development, but I've been writing iOS software for the past 7 years. I'm not a complete noob.
Here's the issue I'm having. I'm having a minimised Javascript file which is inserted in the website on the internet. How can edit the original source, while testing this on the website online where the bug in the Javascript is appearing.
Google Chrome appears to have a function like that, but I can't seem to make it work. Any tips, resources or explanation so I can get this thing figured out?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Usually you edit the non minified version and then re-minify

Comment: I already have the original Javascript file.

Comment: Is there an easy way to load and edit the original javascript file in to the website?

Comment: Ususally, when you minify the JS file, you can create a corresponding map file which you can use to map your errors in the minified version to the unminified version. Alternatively, in chrome, at the bottom of the source tab when you have a minified file open, there will be a button with this symbol `{}` at the bottom. Click that to format the minified code and debug from there. (The disadvantage of this is that any code mangling will still be retained)

Comment: @Imakemymark if you have the original file, you can change the HTML source to point to that (just give the original file's path where the minified path is given now). Then you can edit the original file and see changes by refreshing the page.

Comment: if the JS isn't yours, chances are there is an *unminified* version you can get anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Chrome has "overrides" function which allows this.

Step 1: enable overrides

F12 > Sources > Overrides (in the left tab) > Enable Local overrides

You'll need to provide a path for it to save the scripts

Step 2: go

F12 > Sources > Network > Locate the relevant JS file > right-click > save for override

Go back to Overrides, navigate to the file and edit it. CTRL+S to save, then F5 to reload. Since you have the original javascript, you might as well replace the minified source with the original in the override.

Comment: Also, learn from my mistakes: remember to disable the override when you're done to avoid wasting time wondering why you don't see the latest changes made by your colleague...

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I was looking for me. Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
[Unminify JS](http://www.unminify.org/)

PS use KOALA for the minification of your CSS/JS.
[Koala](http://koala-app.com/)

Comment: I know how to do minimise it. I have the original and a minimised version. And the last one is loaded on the website. I need to fix a bug in the script while working on a life environment from someone else.